# python if list_item == re.match

Tags: python, if-statement, design-patterns, match, python-re

I'm trying to practice regex patterns with conditions in python (googlecollab), but stuck in (if... and...) by getting proper numbers from the list[000 to 999] - i need only numbers, ending with one digit '1' (not 11, 111, 211 - I need only 001, 021, 031, 101), but it returns nothing with multiple condition... if I clear code starting with 'and' in condition - it returns all ones, elevens, hundred elevens...

```
list_ = []
list_.append('000')
for a in range(999):
    list_.append(str(a+1))

for i, el in  enumerate(list_):
    if len(el) == 1:
        list_[i] = '00'+el
    elif len(el) == 2:
        list_[i] = '0'+el

for item in list_:
    try:
        if item == re.match(r'\d\d1', item).group() \
        and item != re.match(r'\d11', item).group():
            print(item) 
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Side note: your list generation code can be simplified to `list_ = [str(x).zfill(3) for x in range(1000)]`

Comment: You can look for a 1 at the end of a string using [$](https://pythonexamples.org/python-regex-check-if-string-ends-with-specific-word/). Also, I wouldn't compare your `item` to the match, but rather check if the match is non-empty.

Comment: Instead of `zfill` you could use `f"{i:03d}"`.

Comment: Johnny Mopp, BRemmelzwaal, RomanPerekhrest, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only "numbers" which end with one(not more) digit `1` use the following regex pattern:

```
for i in list_:
    m = re.match(r'\d(0|[2-9])1$', i)
    if m:
        print(i)
```

---

- `(0|[2-9])` - alternation group: to match either `0` or any in range `2-9`

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use a try catch without actually doing nothing, it would just hide the error.
2. match() doesn't return a string but a match object, can't use the == operator, but the return will be None if no match are foun so for a quick fix you can write it as:

```
if re.match(r'\d\d1', item) is not None
```

3. you can use [] to specify all digit except 1 as [023456789] instead of using the and as in:

```
if re.match(r'\d[023456789]1', item) is not None:
```

4. matchall() seems more fititng here, give it a look.